# Tensorflow Dataset/Iterator for evaluating with train and test data in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

The setting: I want to predict a value by training a CNN on input batches in a regression setting. I also want to evaluate and calculate the loss after every epoch, so I need to switch between datasets at runtime.

```
Input: [num_examples, height, width, channels] -> [num_examples, y]
```

I want to use the new Dataset API because I want to avoid feeding batches myself during the training.

I also **don't** want to store my dataset in the computation graph because the Dataset is bigger than 2GB, **but** small enough to be stored in memory.

This is my current setup:

```
def initialize_datasets(x, y,...):
    dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    dataset_train = dataset_train.apply(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=examples_train, count=epochs))
    dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(batch_size)

    dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    dataset_test = dataset_test.apply(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=examples_test, count=-1))
    dataset_test = dataset_test.batch(batch_size)

    # Iterator 
    iterator_train = dataset_train.make_initializable_iterator()
    iterator_test = dataset_test.make_initializable_iterator()

    return iterator_train, iterator_test


def get_input_batch_data(testing, iterator_train, iterator_test):
    features, labels = tf.cond(testing, lambda: iterator_test.get_next(), lambda: iterator_train.get_next())
    return features, labels
```

Then in `my model()` function:

```
#1
iterator_train, iterator_test = initialize_datasets(x, y, ...)
#2
features, labels = get_input_batch_data(testing, iterator_train, 
iterator_test)

# forward pass, loss, etc
...

with tf.Session as sess:
   #initialize with train data, trainX[num_examples, height, width, channels]
    sess.run(iterator_train.initializer, feed_dict={x: trainX, y: trainY, 
    batch_size: batchsize})

   #initialize with test data
    sess.run(iterator_test.initializer, feed_dict={x: testX, y: testY, 
    batch_size: NUM_EXAMPLES_TEST})

for i in range(EPOCHS)
    for j in range(NUM_BATCHES)
        _, batch_loss = sess.run([train_step, loss], feed_dict={testing: 
              False,  i: iters_total, pkeep: p_keep})   

    # after 1 epoch, calculate loss and whole test data set
    epoch_test_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={testing: True, i: 
                    iters_total, pkeep: 1})
```

This is the output:

```
Iter: 44, Epoch: 0 (8.46s), Train-Loss: 103011.18, Test-Loss: 100162.34
Iter: 89, Epoch: 1 (4.17s), Train-Loss: 93699.51, Test-Loss: 92130.21
Iter: 134, Epoch: 2 (4.13s), Train-Loss: 90217.82, Test-Loss: 88978.74
Iter: 179, Epoch: 3 (4.14s), Train-Loss: 88503.13, Test-Loss: 87515.81
Iter: 224, Epoch: 4 (4.18s), Train-Loss: 87336.62, Test-Loss: 86486.40
Iter: 269, Epoch: 5 (4.10s), Train-Loss: 86388.38, Test-Loss: 85637.64
Iter: 314, Epoch: 6 (4.14s), Train-Loss: 85534.52, Test-Loss: 84858.43
Iter: 359, Epoch: 7 (4.29s), Train-Loss: 84693.19, Test-Loss: 84074.78
Iter: 404, Epoch: 8 (4.20s), Train-Loss: 83973.64, Test-Loss: 83314.47
Iter: 449, Epoch: 9 (4.40s), Train-Loss: 83149.73, Test-Loss: 82541.73
```

Problems:

- This output indicates to me that my dataset pipeline didn't work because either the the test loss is calculated on the train data or vice versa because these losses are too close to each other
- What kind of iterators and dataset would I use to perform this task?

I also uploaded the whole model here: https://github.com/toemm/TF-CNN-regression/blob/master/BA-CNN_so.ipynb

Comment: You way is a bad idea. The prediction graph should be completely different! Otherwise, you get wrong results, e.g., Dropout or BatchNorm updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious answer is: You do not want to do this within the *same* graph as the evaluation graph is different from the training graph.

- Dropout has fixed multiplier (no sampling)
- BatchNorm uses accumulated statistics and does **not** update the EMA

So the solution is really to build two different things like

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


X_train = tf.constant(np.ones((100, 2)), 'float32')
X_val = tf.constant(np.zeros((10, 2)), 'float32')

iter_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    X_train).make_initializable_iterator()
iter_val = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    X_val).make_initializable_iterator()


def graph(x, is_train=True):
  return x


output_train = graph(iter_train.get_next(), is_train=True)
output_val = graph(iter_val.get_next(), is_train=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(iter_train.initializer)
  sess.run(iter_val.initializer)

  for train_iter in range(100):
    print(sess.run(output_train))

  for train_iter in range(10):
    print(sess.run(output_val))
```